# Opening a modal in a function call instead of .click()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this jquery function that opens up a modal anytime a button is pressed of type 'btnClr'

```
$(document).ready(function () {
                $('#[id*=btnClr]').onload(function () {
                    $dialog.dialog('open');
                });

                var $dialog = $("#trUI").dialog({
                    autoOpen: false,
                    title: "Edit Configurations",
                    width: "auto",
                    buttons: {
                        "Submit": function (e) {
                            AddKeyValue();
                            $(this).dialog('close');
                        },
                        "Cancel": function (e) {
                            ClearKeyVal();
                            $(this).dialog('close');
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
```

I'm trying to move it into a function so that it's opened anytime the function is called instead of any time the button is clicked.

I was able to achieve this with this code

```
function modalOpen() {

                        var $dialog = $("#trUI")
                            .dialog({
                                title: "Edit Configurations",
                                width: "auto",
                                buttons: {
                                    "Submit": function(e) {
                                        AddKeyValue();
                                        $(this).dialog('close');
                                    },
                                    "Cancel": function(e) {
                                        ClearKeyVal();
                                        $(this).dialog('close');
                                    }
                                }
                            });
            }
```

However, any one of the buttons will only work once.

Does anybody have any recommendations for how to do this?

Comment: Define the modal once, set autoOpen to false, and then just call the .dialog("open") and .dialog("close") whenever you want to open/close it. You don't need to redefine it each time you call the function - it's probably what is causing the errors

Comment: this doesn't seem to work. Unless I'm defining the modal wrong, this just reloads the page every time a button is clicked with no modal appearing

Answer (score 0):

I believe your issue is that you also are not "opening" the dialog. Move  $dialog.dialog('open'); into the new function you wrote, so whenever it is called it will open it.

Comment: The second example I have above will actually open the modal on the first click of the button just as it should. However, once I close the modal and try to open it again, it doesn't work

Comment: I can't tell what is wrong without the rest of the code. DO you have a jsfiddle I can look at? I still believe it is because of the dialog.open.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it working. It was a TINY change in code. All I had to change was the call to dialog("open")

```
 // some function{
$("#trUI").dialog('open'); //instead of $dialog.dialog("open")
}

$(document).ready(function () {
                $("#trUI").dialog({
                    autoOpen: false,
                    title: "Edit Configurations",
                    width: "auto",
                    buttons: {
                        "Submit": function (e) {
                            AddKeyValue();
                            $(this).dialog('close');
                        },
                        "Cancel": function (e) {
                            ClearKeyVal();
                            $(this).dialog('close');
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
```